# How to apply pandas udf to large matrix dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I am really new to Spark and Pandas. I would like to apply pandas UDF for large matrix of numpy.ndarray that doesn't have any column name. How should I define the input for the UDF function?

This is what I did. row is a row from the cassandra database and 'b2' is a column name for an image inside the database.

```
def normalize_i(I):
    iI=I
    minI=20#np.min(I)
    maxI=50#np.max(I)
    minO=0
    maxO=255
    iI = (256.0/65536)*iI
    io=(iI-minI)*(((maxO-minO)/(maxI-minI))+minO)
    return io

b2 = cPickle.loads(row.asDict()['b2'], encoding='bytes')
pdf = pd.DataFrame(b2,columns=["x"])
dfb2 = spark.createDataFrame(pdf)
dfb2.select(normalize_i(col("x")))
```

As expected 
`pd.DataFrame(b2,columns=["x"])`
returns an error since b2 is array of array:
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (324, 324), indices imply (324, 1)

How should I define the column name for my dataframe, and the input for my function?

Any comment would be much appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

can you please detail what pdf should look like?

If b2 is 324x324, i guess you should give 324 columns names:

```
columns = ['x'+str(i) for i in range(b2.shape[1])]
```

Comment: Thank you, I never thought we could give the name for column with iterator. Yes, b2 is a numpy.ndarray with 324x324. Now, I wonder how to use the column name as input for the UDF. Any idea?